# How to create full year entry in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, momentjs

I want to create a table where complete 365 days entry (or leap year) will be stored on utc format which further read as Indian Time stamp i.e + 5:30

So lets say I have to create the entry of 2020, then start entry will like

```
2019-12-31T18:30:000  --> On indian time stamp it will be sharp 00 1 JAN 2020
2020-12-31T18:29:59:999  --> 23:59 31 DEC 2020

So suppose these entry is stored, now When any request comes then check the query through {$gte: new Date()}
```

I will create the system cron which call this function on 1jan 00:00 so that every year I have the Correct entry.
This is my approach to fetch the Data. Now I don't understand that how to create the entry because this will be not meaningfull if I miss any date entry.

I take the moment help but not getting success on that. Is there anyone who can guide me for that.

Comment: UTC is a time standard, not a format. You might mean ISO 8601 format, which would be 2019-12-31T18:30:00Z (though there are other ISO 8601 formats for the same moment in time).

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler to generate that list on the client send and send a bulk insert.  If you really want to create it on the server, you could use aggregation, run this against a collection with at least one document in it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {
      dateFrom: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30"),
      dateTo: ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00+05:30")
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      date: {$range: [0, 366]}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$date"},
  {$addFields: {
      date: {
        $add: [
          "$dateFrom",
          {$multiply: [ "$date",86400000 ]}
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: ["$date", "$dateTo"]
      }
  }},
  {$project: { date: 1 }},
  {$out: "NewCollectionForDates"}
])
```